# How to Validate different model class into one form using Spring MVC JSR-303 Validator

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have form inside `jsp` page as below:

```
<springForm:form action="${addAction}" name="frm" method="post" commandName="employee">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>First Name</label>   </td>
            <td><springForm:input path="firstName" /></td>
            <td><springForm:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Last Name</label></td>
            <td><springForm:input path="lastName" /></td>
            <td><springForm:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Email</label>    </td>
            <td><springForm:input path="email" /></td>
            <td><springForm:errors path="email" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Street</label>   </td>
            <td><springForm:input path="employeeDetail.street" /></td>
            <td><springForm:errors path="employeeDetail.street" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>City</label> </td>
            <td><springForm:input path="employeeDetail.city" /></td>
            <td><springForm:errors path="employeeDetail.city" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>State</label>    </td>
            <td><springForm:input path="employeeDetail.state" /></td>
            <td><springForm:errors path="employeeDetail.state" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Country</label>  </td>
            <td><springForm:input path="employeeDetail.country" /></td>
            <td><springForm:errors path="employeeDetail.country" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="submit" value="Add Info" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</springForm:form>
```

In this jsp First Name, Last Name and email belong to a model class i.e Employee.
Last all attributes like Street, City etc belong to EmployeeDetails model class.

```
public class Employee {

private Long empId;

@Size(min=2, max=30)
private String firstName;

@Size(min=2, max=30)
private String lastName;

@NotEmpty @Email
private String email;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
@NotNull @Past
private Date doj;

@Phone
private String phone;

private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;

Getter/Setter
}
```

EmployeeDetail:

```
public class EmployeeDetail {

@Size(min=2, max=30)
private String street;

@Size(min=2, max=30)
private String city;

@Size(min=2, max=30)
private String state;

@Size(min=2, max=30)
private String country;
//Getter/Setter
}
```

I am performing validation on both model inside a single form. My Cotroller mapping is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveEmpInfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveEmployee(@Valid Employee employee,
        @Valid EmployeeDetail employeeDetail, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    employee.setEmployeeDetail(employeeDetail);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("Returning addInfo.jsp page");
        return "addInfo";
    }
    //future logic
}
```

But It's not working getting Bad Request.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work you should annotate employeeDetails with @Valid in your Employee.class like this:

```
@Valid
private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;
```

And now in controller you should use just Employee object like this:

```
public String saveEmployee(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

Comment: Thanks @jgr for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You should change the names of the attributes belong to `EmployeeDetail` from e.g. `name="street"` to `name="employeeDetail.street"`

Also, you should add a `BindingResult` object right behind the `Employee` argument as well, so that the framework can store the binding error related to Employee, the current BindingResult will apply only to `EmployeeDetail` instance, so

```
saveEmployee(@Valid Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResultEmployee,
        @Valid EmployeeDetail employeeDetail, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

without it you're getting a bad request, with it, the request will actually reach the method, and the logs will show the exact binding error if set to debug level

Comment: Now its working and getting the values on controller mapping. But when EmployeeDetail model attributes are blank its not showing the errors. I have included <springForm:errors path="employeeDetail.street" cssClass="error" /> as well.

Comment: I've edited the answer as well, Spring MVC will instantiate the nested object and will propagate the validation, there's no need to mark `EmployeeDetail` as a separate argument

Comment: No its not working. We need two separate objects for `Employee` and `EmployeeDetail` with two `BindingResult` objects, as you mentioned earlier in your answer. But problem is that the error messages are not showing for the blank attributes of the `EmployeeDetail` model.